# Insert results from concatenated statement in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

Given two fields in a table, how can I use the results of a `CONCAT` query to populate the results of a third column in the same table?

```
SELECT CONCAT (`field`, '-', `field2`) from `bgt_table`
```

prints out the correct format, but how can I insert the results in the appropriate row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE bgt_table
SET thirdColumn = CONCAT (`field`, '-', `field2`)
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE `bgt_table` SET `field3` = CONCAT(`field`,'-',`field2`);